# How to fix "is only supported on: 'Windows' 7.0 and later"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, target-framework

I have to double-target a project that currently runs on `net48`. I've updated target frameworks this way

```
<TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

But this gives me a lot of warnings `CA1416` like *... is only supported on: 'Windows' 7.0 and later.*

I tried

```
<TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0-windows8.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

but result is the same. How can I tell compiler that I only care about Windows versions started with some version? I understand that I can suppress this warning but I don't know want to suppress similar warnings with other Windows versions, not 7.0 but, say, 8.0 or 10.0.x.x.

---

Some types that raise this warning:

```
CspParameters, X509CertificateBindingManager, X509CertificateBuilder
```

Comment: Seems you have code that can only run on, say, android or linux.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the question. I hoped it is evident from the warning that the current code runs fine on Windows.

Comment: there is no reason to target windows, .net is cross platform, if you're targeting 4.8 and also want to target 8 you likely would need to target .net standard instead to cover both.

Comment: @AdamHess friends don't let friends target netstandard (without very good reason); in almost all cases, multi-targeting (as shown in the question) is preferable, just: use an appropriate `#if` or runtime check around relevant platform-specific code

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms), [.NET SDK uses a smaller RID graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/rid-graph), [.NET RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#known-rids)